# autoplay video issue

Tags: video, vimeo, autoplay, vimeo-player

I have a vimeo video embedded in a hidden div. When I click a link, the video pops up with fancybox, and the autoplay starts.

My problem is in Chrome, the video starts playing directly when I entering the site, and you can here the backgroundmusic of the video.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could fix this:

1. Wait to write the iframe into the lightbox until right when the user clicks to open it.
2. Remove `autoplay` from the iframe src and use the [`play()`](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#methods) function to start playback when the lightbox opens.